# check if word exist in table

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have  built a datatable as in picture .. i shall inter sentence in a textbox  such as: "the boy kick the ball " i need to check each word of that sentence if it does exist in that table so it will display the  name of the column that contains the word in a listbox such as:(the => Article).
i did all the steps but i stops in the last step of checking and displaying the name of the column that contains the word..
i'm just a beginner so it becomes hard to me to programming the last steps would any one help me please???
[datatable has three columns "Article","Noun","verb"
and rows values:"the","boy","kick" and so on in other rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAQPG.png)

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn article = new DataColumn("Article", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(article);
        DataColumn noun = new DataColumn("Noun", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(noun);
        DataColumn verb = new DataColumn("Verb", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(verb);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Article"] = "the";
        dr["Noun"] = "boy";
        dr["Verb"] = "kick";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        DataRow dd = dt.NewRow();
        dd["Article"] = "a";
        dd["Noun"] = "ball";
        dd["Verb"] = "eat";
        dt.Rows.Add(dd);
        dd = dt.NewRow();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        string s = textBox1.Text;
        string[] st = s.Split(' ');
```

now how to check each word in st[] if it does exist in the table
he will display the word and the name of the column he found it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn article = new DataColumn("Article", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(article);
            DataColumn noun = new DataColumn("Noun", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(noun);
            DataColumn verb = new DataColumn("Verb", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(verb);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Article"] = "the";
            dr["Noun"] = "boy";
            dr["Verb"] = "kick";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            DataRow dd = dt.NewRow();
            dd["Article"] = "a";
            dd["Noun"] = "ball";
            dd["Verb"] = "eat";
            dt.Rows.Add(dd);
            dd = dt.NewRow();

            string s = "the boy eat the ball"; //textBox1.Text;
            string[] st = s.Split(' ');
        
            foreach (var str in st)
            {
                foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if(str == rows["Article"].ToString())
                        Console.WriteLine("Word=" + str + "    Column=Article");
                    else if (str == rows["Noun"].ToString())
                        Console.WriteLine("Word=" + str + "    Column=Noun");
                    else if (str == rows["Verb"].ToString())
                        Console.WriteLine("Word=" + str + "    Column=Verb");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Word=the    Column=Article
>
> Word=ball    Column=Noun
>
> Word=eat    Column=Verb
>
> Word=a    Column=Article
>
> Word=boy    Column=Noun

Comment: at this condition ' if (str == rows["Article"].ToString()) ' shows an error : Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: I have edited my answer to include my full code. See if you can compile.